# I am wondering why this small program takes O(N) to proceed

Tags: java, performance, algorithm, analysis, recurrence

```java
private void listAll( int depth )
{
    printName( depth ); // Print the name of the object
    if( isDirectory( ) )
    for each file c in this directory (for each child)
    c.listAll( depth + 1 );
}
```

I tries to use recurrence relation to induce the running time
The right running time is O(N)
My analysis shows that it would be O(N^2)

Here is my induction
1. T(0) = (Line one) O(1)+(Line 2) O(1)+(the children number we assume is N) N*(T(1)
2. T(0) = (Line one) O(1)+(Line 2) O(1)+ N*(O(1)+O(1)+ N*(T(2))
3  As this induction goes on, the running time will be some kind of O(N^2)

What is the problem in my analysis???

Comment: how are you calculating your running time?

Comment: Why would it be exponential? There are N files.

Comment: What is the `N` here?

Comment: Looks like you're finding T(0) in terms of T(1), and then in terms of T(2), etc. But isn't that backwards? Shouldn't you find T(1) in terms of T(0), and T(2) in terms of T(1) and/or T(0)?

Comment: @DanielA.White A. White ,Hey actually I am calculating the running time, I am just wonder the relation between he running time and the input size. The question is that this algorithm is O(N) but how to prove it? My induction indicates that it is O(N^2).

Comment: @DaveNewton, Hey, you are right , but what is wrong with my analysis??

Comment: The part where you multiply N by N. There's nothing in there that says "for each N we have to run it through N times"; you never *repeat* anything.

Answer (score 4):

Your error is in assuming N children. If N is the total number of files, you should observe O(N) runtime.

Answer (score 0):

You perhaps misunderstood what the N means? Perhaps the N is the number of all files in the root directory and all its subdirectories, which would make this problem Depth-First Search, which has O(N) complexity, where N is the number of nodes.

If it indeed were N^2, then the number of files in one directory and in the other would have to have some dependency. But it is not so... the number of files in each folder is undefined unless you actually visit it. It can be 2, it can ten thousand.

Answer (score 0):

If by single step you mean a single call to `listAll()` and `N` is total number of elements in directory structure, it must be that one call to `listAll()` must correspond to the single element, otherwise you would get at least one element printed more than once.

Hence, you get `O(N)` (actually, exactly N * recursive_call_cost)